# rosrun beginner_tutorials error

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the beginner tutorial, when I run

> roscore

then from within `catkin_ws` I run

> catkin_make

> rosrun beginner_tutorials talker

I am geting an error

> [rospack] Error: package
> 'beginner_tutorials' not found

what would cause this error?
could it be file ownership?  so far everything was thru command line but after i installed eclipse this error started happening.

when i run

> rosrun roscpp_tutorials talker

it runs ok but I am not sure where this package resides.

**FIXED**: http://answers.ros.org/question/71260/ros-beginner-tutorials-examining-the-simple-service-and-client-python-need-some-help-with-client-2/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207743/rosrun-beginner_tutorials-error/) by [s1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21751/s1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From within the catkin_ws: `source devel/setup.bash`, then try to `rosrun` again.

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [s1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21751/s1/) on 2015-04-24**:
when do i need to "source" catkin_ws? in other words what would cause me to have to do this?

**Comment by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on 2015-04-24**:
So the script `setup.bash` is a config script that will set some environment variables. Without those variables being set then ROS is not aware of the new executables that you have created during build.

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-04-25**:
source the environment

**Comment by [s1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21751/s1/) on 2015-04-27**:
I thought `catkin_make` took care of compiling node changes